# need help identifing IC's and symbols from a diagram

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, symbol

I am tring to make a circuit and need to purchase the required components but there are some IC's that I can not identify. I tried to google them up but I haven't found anything helpful yet.I also can't understand a few symbols on the diagram, and I want to know what they represent.
the top 3 images are the components. 
the bottom 2 imaged are the symbols. what does the green triangle mean? im guessing that the pentagonal blue block is a direct input but i am not sure, also whats the red circle above it?. 
in the bottom most image, are the red and blue boxes (with 1 and 0's in them) input as well? and what are the smaller red and blue boxes under them?
thats it for now. i'm sorry if these questions are very basic, i am new to this so bear with me.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a hand-drawn schematic, it looks like it was generated by some kind of CAD schematic entry tool -- so perhaps there's a Bill of Materials or a Parts List among the project files?

Comment: Looks like U5 is a `CD4532B CMOS 8-bit Priority Encoder` http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4532b.pdf
When ordering, note there are different package types. PDIP is plastic dual-in-line package like you could plug into an old-school solderless breadboard, but SOIC / SO / TSSOP are surface-mount packages that must be soldered to a printed circuit board.

Comment: Looks like U19 is a `CD4508B CMOS Dual 4-bit Latch` http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4508b.pdf  This is a "dual" latch, so one of the latches is U19A and the other latch is U19B; both on the same silicon chip inside the same package.

Comment: The green triangles are probably "offpage" flags: every offpage flag with the net name "STATUS_2ND", on every page, are all connected together. And every offpage flag named "STATUS_1ST" are all connected. But nets with different names do not connect; only nets with the same name connect.

Answer (score 1):

1. The three components above are Integrated Circuits, or more vulgarly chips. If you want to search them on Internet for each one, add the 'datasheet' word to the one in question (Can't see the numbers clearly, but they seem 4532, 4508, 4572).
2. All the other question you asked seem to be, to some extent, specific to a certain software that has been used to make these diagrams. If you don't know, try to know what software was used to do the job, and then get to its help/manual/documentation.

Comment: The second one is a 4508. And all should be preceded by a CD - CD4532, CD4508, CD4572.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Thanks for correction; edited according to your observations. Pixelometric vision is not one of my strengths.